# Parametrizing straight lines intersecting a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I've got a point $ P (-1,1,2) $ and the circle $ C: ~ (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 = \dfrac {25} {4} $ (which is contained in the plane: $ z=0 $). I need to write the parametric equations of all straight lines that go through $P$ and intersect $C$.

I know it must be something like: $ \dfrac {x+1} {\lambda_1} =  \dfrac {y-1} {\lambda_2} =  \dfrac {z-2} {\lambda_3} $ and then transform it to parametric. But my knowledge here weakens and I don't know how to indicate the straight lines that intersect $C$.

Furthermore, after that I need one straight line from that bundle that cuts $s: ~ \{x=a, y=3.5, z=-2; ~ a \in \mathbb{R}_0^+ \} $

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have the flat circle ${(x-1)}^2 + {(y-1)}^2 = \frac{25}{4}$, not a cylinder, as z=0.  You need to choose a parameter.  Angle is often a good choice for circles.  Let $0 ≤ \theta ≤ 2\pi$.  Then $x = 1+\frac{5}{2}cos \theta $ and $y =1+\frac{5}{2}sin \theta $. Find the equation of the line through such a point and your given point.